# Почему не меняется картинка профиля?

Tags: php, javascript, html, wordpress

На сайте присутствует профиль пользователя, на котором есть картинка, ее можно изменить путем загрузки фото с компьютера. После выбора фото и нажатии кнопки сохранить, отображается старая картинка, новая появляется лишь после обновления страницы с помощью Ctrl + F5. Как исправить проблему? Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это не проблема, а особенность работы браузера. Если имя картинки не меняется, то браузер берет её из кеша, а не загружает из интернета. Принудительное обновление страницы через Ctrl + F5 заставляет обновить кеш браузера.
Чтобы заставить каждый раз загружать картинку из интернета можно добавить к адресу картинки параметр (например, время создания файла с изображением, или добавить текущее время, в этом случае картинка будет загружаться из интернета даже в том, случае если она не обновлялась)

```
<img src="/image/avatar_12345.png?<?=time()?>">
```

Comment: Так дело в том, что имя то разное...я же загружаю фото с компьютера, а фото разные, с разными названиями, при этом они не меняют старые до очистки кэша...

Comment: Нажмите Ctrl+Shft+J в браузере, исследуйте эту картинку, посмотрите название. Имя картинки не будет совпадать с тем именем, с каким оно было на вашем компьютере. CMS обычно присваивают другое имя картинкам, и для аватара пользователя это имя может не меняться, даже если у вас на компьютере имена этих файлов разные.

Comment: Хорошо, спасибо за разъяснение, но куда же мне этот код прописать? Сам вывод картинки осуществляется с помощью:  get_avatar();

Comment: Вам важно понять, что это не проблема, это просто особенность браузера. У всех пользователей вашего сайта проблем не будет, но этот момент только доставляет вам неудобства как разработчику, тем, что вам приходится каждый раз нажимать Ctrl+F5.
Правильней с вашей стороны, это вообще ничего не делать, а продолжать работать как есть - у вас и кроме аватара есть другие задачи.
Добавление параметра для картинки - это достаточно специфичная вещь, и нужна только для того, чтобы запретить браузеру кешировать картинки. Но такие вещи нужны крайне редко.

Comment: Хорошо, вернусь к этому уже в конце... Еще раз спасибо!)